# Query JSON file in Presto in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, presto, trino, json-extract

I have a file in S3, and Presto running on EMR. I see I can use Json_extract to read the json.

I am running the following query, however, I keep seeing null instead of the correct value.

```
select json_extract('s3a://random-s3-bucket/analytics/20210221/myjsonfile.json', '$.dateAvailability')
```

I see this output

[image]

Not sure if my syntax is wrong? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`json_extract()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract) operates on JSON scalar values kept in memory. It does not load data from an external location. See documentation page for usage examples.

In order to query a JSON file using Trino ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)), you need to map it as a table with JSON format like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ( .... )
WITH (
    format = 'JSON',
    external_location = 's3a://random-s3-bucket/analytics/20210221'
);
```

See more information in [Hive connector documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html).

Comment: JSON format table have ROW object which will allow us to get nested JSON block. Can we further parse this ROW object in create table statement it self for accessing fields directly with name instead of row_object.field_name?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a tool to help you create the table statement, try this one: https://www.hivetablegenerator.com

From the page:

> Easily convert any JSON (even complex Nested ones), CSV, TSV, or Log
> sample file to an Apache HiveQL DDL create table statement.